# Deploying Django Application

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, amazon-web-services

So I am quite the beginner in the world of web development. I have been working on a django application, and now that my application is running pretty well I am staring into the face of the monster that is deployment, and wondering which direction to take.

My application is running Django 1.7 and Python 3.4. I want to use PostgreSQL with Postgis as my database. I was originally thinking of using Amazon AWS for deployment, using their Elastic Beanstalk PaaS service, although now I am wondering if something like Heroku may be better for me as a beginner to all of this. I need my application to scale easily, without me having to dive into too much configuration that I am very likely to mess up.

What I am wondering is which service would be best for a newcomer developer deploying an application running the platforms I mentioned above. Heroku seems like it is a bit easier to use than AWS, but I am concerned that the pricing with Heroku would ramp up more quickly than with AWS. How difficult would it be to initially deploy using one service and migrate to another as I become more familiar with the process of maintaining web applications and/or as my needs change?

Any recommendations or info to help me decide on a service to go with would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can I plug the company I work for, [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com)?  Making Python application deployment easy is pretty much what we're there for :-)

Postgres support (including PosGIS) is currently in beta, but is pretty solid -- if you sign up, just drop us a line and we can enable it for your account.

Comment: +1. Just started using the service over last weekend, and so far things have been perfect. Can't comment on heavy production use yet, but the initial deployment pain is very seriously alleviated, to the point that you don't feel that at all. Web-based consoles are great, feels much like desktop experience. And that's true even for a free account! The disclaimer is that I am not an expert in Python / Django (rather a beginner), but I guess this is actually a plus in the context of this question.

Comment: Initially deployed to Heroku after asking this question, then decided I wasn't ready for their $50 a month DB just to use PostGIS, so I ported over to PythonAnywhere today, since PostGIS is much less expensive. VERY easy to use. I got my Django app up and running linked to a Bonsai Elasticsearch worker in an hour or two... Only problem is that as far as I can tell celery is not supported... which might be a big issue if I cannot find a sufficient work-around.

Comment: I spotted a post on our forums today about Celery, perhaps that's you?  If not (or for anyone else reading here), here's a link: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1871/ -- hopefully we can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying Django service using postgres at AWS is as easy as you use local server, AWS is easy and good to use, you just need to confgiure `confuguration` file of Postgres and `server` you install at AWS. go to this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn if you are using `Apache`.